# Stopping lightdm service is giving black screen, can't install nVidia GeForce GTX 960 drivers

Tags: lightdm, nvidia-geforce

I seem to have a peculiar problem regarding my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS box.
I have nVidia GeForce GTX 960 graphics card.
Untill a few days before I used to get the latest drivers from the nVidia's official site and install them the usual way. (Logging in at tty1, turning off lightdm service and install drivers from the .run file)
But when I downloaded the latest drivers again a couple of days back and tried to install them as above, I was disappointed to find that turning off the lightdm service is giving me black screen. The machine is running fine behind the black screen because I can press up arrow and restart lightdm service which gives me back my gui well and working.
I am not a seasoned sys-admin. But can get around the file system and general cli stuff.
Can anybody explain what is going wrong in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem is here:

> I am not a seasoned sys-admin.

... as you're attempting things that requires some knowledge.

If you see it as absolutely necessary to have the VERY latest drivers, I'd recommend that you do replace the graphics driver while it is NOT in use:

i.e. use the recovery mode from the boot (GRUB) menu,

- run fsck from the menu that comes up (remounts disks present in fstab, in rw mode),
- enable networking (also in the menu)
- and then start the bash prompt
- `--uninstall` the previous driver before doing anything else at the prompt.

Also note that the above is an outline of the process, there might be other necessary steps - e.g. mounting disks or similar; which depends on your setup, where you put the downloaded file and so on.

Comment: Yup, guilty as charged. Learning nuts and bolts of Linux is now top on my 'to-do' list. As to my problem, I COULD in fact install the nvidia drivers using your instructions. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using the system settings in Unity to change your display drivers. You can go to your Dash and search for `Additional Drivers`. That should list what alternative drivers are available for your hardware, and you shouldn't have to manually stop and start lightdm.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to sort me out. But unfortunately, the Additional Drivers only tell me that a 'Proprietary Driver is in use' and I want my system to have latest possible drivers (I work on a lot of graphics-related programs.) Though your suggestion definitely helps a new installation since the drivers installed from the Additional Drivers utility appear to be more stable than the manually installed ones. Thanks again.